# Operations with vars and numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try simple thing , add number to var , for example :

```
<script>
function pag(id)
{
var valur=(id+1);
alert(""+valur);
}
</script>

<a href="javascript:pag('1');">More</a>
```

Always i get 1 and 1 no 2 , 3 , etc , anc continue , which the problem in this ?

Thank´s for the help

Answer (score 3):

Your first problem is that you're calling the function with a string, not a number. `'1' + 1` is `'11'`, but `1 + 1` is 2.

Your second problem is that you're not saving the new value anywhere; you just keep calling the function with `1`. You need to use a variable.

Here's the fixed code:

```
<script>
var valur = 1;
function pag()
{
    ++valur; // add one
    alert(valur);
}
</script>

<a href="javascript:pag();">More</a>
```

Comment: I think you don understand me , the id add 1 to the amount and continue in each click add 1 , the id it´s in function i can´t have var out , regards

Comment: @user2912997 You can't save state without using variables.

Comment: I need add and increase number with id